# Конвенция именования файлов разделяемых(partial) классов и методов

Tags: c#, .net

Существуют ли какие-то правила именования файлов разделяемого кода?

Скажем, я хочу часть методов вынести в один файл, часть в другую, а инициализацию каких-нибудь коллекций-полей 10-ом значений в 3-ий(что бы не мозолила глаза).

Как правильно и красиво назвать файлы-кода?

Comment: Так чтобы было понятно, обычно дополнение отделяют точкой, типа `MyClass.Initialization.cs`

Comment: А разделенные файлы внутренних типов как-то по особенному называются? Ну скажем, я решил объявить внутренний класс в отдельном файле.

Comment: Ну лично я бы назвал бы по имени этого внутреннего класса: `MyClass.NestedClass.cs`

Comment: Если вам надо разделять классы на файлы, то, скорее всего, вы нарушаете S из SOLID. Попробуйте подумать над причиной этого разделения, может есть вариант разделить код на раззные классы?

Comment: Не согласен, что нарушается S. Класс может использоваться как вспомогательный (только например для использования внутри текущего namespace класса, в котором размещается вспомогательный класс)